# Problems using Diskpart to resolve 'Read Only' issue on external 2TB external MyBook

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, read-only, diskpart, mybook

I've got a problem with an external disk which suddenly, mid-session decided it was read only. I've tried the right click, properties, attributes, read only - to no avail, so then decided to approach the problem through Diskpart.

Diskpart shows external drive when the query is LIST DISK, however it does not show up when the query is LIST VOLUME. I'm trying to run a ATTR VOLUME CLEAR READONLY command to clear the 'read only' problem as the 'ATTR DISK CLEAR READONLY' did not work.

System is running 64 bit windows 7 home premium with i5 - 4670K cpu
External drive is a WD MyBook 2Tb (I had another one of these go down a couple of months ago - be warned)

Comment: Back up the drive if there's anything important on it, and go get your money back. An alternative if you're brave may be to use the built-in WD software to get it going again. There may be something in the firmware that's making it read-only.